# http post not getting called when called from ngonit

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to call http post using function displayabsentpresent. But it is not getting called.The console inside subscribe is not getting executed.This is done in angular.I am creating current date in ngonit and calling displayAbsentPresent.printsundaymonday is getting executed.

```
ngOnInit() {
/**Pass from current month onwards...*/
  let dateObj = new Date();
  let monthobj = dateObj.getUTCMonth(); //months from 1-12

  let yearobj = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

  this.printsundaymonday(monthobj, yearobj);

  console.log(+(monthobj +1) + "........date..........." + yearobj);
  this.displayAbsentandPresent(+(monthobj +1),yearobj);


 }

-======================================

 displayAbsentandPresent(month,year) {
console.log(month+ "=================" +year);
  this.postData={
    "year" :year+"",
    "month":month+"",
    "studentid":3+""
    };
    //console.log(this.postData);

       var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }) };
        var count=0;
  this.http.post("http://localhost/android/getattendance.php", JSON.stringify(this.postData),options)


       .subscribe( (data) => { 
         console.log("Getting Post value;Checking inside post .."+data);
         this.setUsersArray(data); 
        }
         );



  this.cd.markForCheck();




 }
```

Here is the full code

https://pastebin.com/raw/Q2QcwXU7

https://pastebin.com/raw/4X4qTDNE

Here is the view

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: @midhunsivarajan, Can you add the data in ```console.log(this.postData);``` that you are sending to post request??

Comment: @Chellappanவ, Seems like ```http``` request itself not gets called bro..

Comment: {year: "2020", month: "3", studentid: "3"}

Comment: But if i call it from monthchanger(event) this is getting called

Comment: @midhunsivarajan, Can you try changing the header to ```'Content-Type': 'application/json'``` instead of ```'text/plain'``` ??

Comment: no it is not still getting called initially

Comment: @midhunsivarajan, Sorry, no idea from my end regarding your issue.. You could check with Postman tool to check the REST API's..

Comment: ok Maniraj.Any way thanks for your effort trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and call that function in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.demoFun();
}
```

```
function demoFun(){
  let dateObj = new Date();
  let monthobj = dateObj.getUTCMonth(); //months from 1-12

  let yearobj = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

  this.printsundaymonday(monthobj, yearobj);

  console.log(+(monthobj +1) + "........date..........." + yearobj);
  this.displayAbsentandPresent(+(monthobj +1),yearobj);
}
```

Comment: Can you please generate sttackblitz link with your code here?